# Not able to return a desired value inside a overidden method using coroutines in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mediasoup

I am new to kotlin and coroutines.I have been working on a client-server part of an android app.I am using [mediasoup-client-android](https://github.com/haiyangwu/mediasoup-client-android) library for this.

I am trying to intialize the sendtransports using createSendTransport() method.This method does have a sendTransportListener which has abstract methods.One of them being is onProduce() which returns a producerId which is a String.  awaitEmit() is an asynchronous action and I need this in onProduce().To use awaitEmit() I used coroutines.But I need String as return type instead of Deferred.Is there any other way to implement the mentioned logic? Below is my code

```
class RoomClient {
 suspend fun initTransports(device: Device) {
    coroutineScope {
        val id: String?
        val iceParameters: String?
        val iceCandidates: String?
        val dtlsParameters: String?
        val sctpParameters: String?
        try {
            val params = JSONObject()
            params.put("forceTcp",false)
            params.put("rtpCapabilities", this@RoomClient.device?.rtpCapabilities)
            val res = socket?.awaitEmit("createWebRtcTransport",params)
            val data = res?.get(0) as JSONObject
            if (data.has("error")) {
                Log.d(TAG, data.getString("error"))
                return@coroutineScope
            }
            id = data.optString("id")
            iceParameters = data.optString("iceParameters")
            iceCandidates = data.optString("iceCandidates")
            dtlsParameters = data.optString("dtlsParameters")
            sctpParameters = data.optString("sctpParameters")
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
            return@coroutineScope
        }
        val sendTransportListener: SendTransport.Listener = object : SendTransport.Listener {
            private val listenerTAG = TAG.toString() + "_ProducerTrans"
            override fun onProduce(
                transport: Transport,
                kind: String?,
                rtpParameters: String?,
                appData: String?
            ): String? {
                this@coroutineScope.async{
                    var producerId: String? = null
                    Log.d(listenerTAG, "onProduce() ")
                    val producerDeferred = launch {
                    val params = JSONObject("""{"producerTransportId": transport.id, "kind": kind, "rtpParameters": rtpParameters,"appData": appData}""")
                    val res = socket?.awaitEmit("produce",params)
                    val data = res?.get(0) as JSONObject
                    producerId = data.getString("producer_Id")
                    }
                    producerDeferred.join()
                    Log.d(listenerTAG, "producerId inside the coroutine: $producerId"
                    }
                return@async producerId
            }
        }
        this@RoomClient.producerTransport = device.createSendTransport(
            sendTransportListener, id,
            iceParameters,
            iceCandidates,
            dtlsParameters
        )

    }
}
```

}

And also I am not sure about the way coroutines are used here.Please correct me If I have missed something central.

Comment: Well, you can't run the code synchronously and asynchronously at the same time ;-) If `onProduce()` has to return the value acquired from `awaitEmit()` then it needs to wait for its result - it has to invoke it synchronously, not asynchronously. Why do you need to run it asynchronously?

Comment: Answering your question, you can replace `launch()` with `async()`, remove `producerId = ` at its end and replace `producerDeferred.join()` with `producerDeferred.await()` - this way you will get a String value. But still, it doesn't make too much sense - it is the same as you would not use launch/async at all.

Comment: awaitEmit() is a suspend function.That is why I used coroutines.Could you tell me  how I can invoke it synchronously?

Comment: Ah, so your question is actually: how to invoke a suspend function from a non-suspend callback. This is confusing to me as well. You can do `runBlocking()`, possibly with your own dispatcher and remove both your `async()` and `launch()`. Unfortunately, this way we risk blocking the thread that we should avoid blocking, but whatever async/launch magic you will perform, you can't (I believe?) avoid this problem. As a fact, I had exactly the same discussion on Kotlin forums just yesterday. I wait for someone from Kotlin team to explain, how to do it properly.

Comment: The above mentioned functioned is invoked when the app lis aunched.Should I go with the runblocking?Is it advisable or  is it the only option we have?

Comment: My understanding (possibly wrong) is that we can't avoid blocking the thread that invoked `onProduce()`. And if this is correct, we have several ways to block, but the easiest is probably to use `runBlocking()`.

Comment: Hi @SatyasaiNeelapala , Were you able to resolve this ? Have you completed this project of mediasoup A/V call? I am also working on this and I am also stucked on similar issue and facing other related problem as well. Can you please post the resolved version of your query ?

Comment: Hi @pravingaikwad07. The problem has not been resolved